# SFINAE to determine if a type has a method

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, template-meta-programming

```
template <typename T>
struct has_xxx {

 private:

  using true_type = char;
  using false_type = long;

  template <typename C>
  static true_type has_xxx_impl(decltype(&C::xxx)); // comment 1

  template <typename C>
  static false_type has_xxx_impl(...); // comment 2

 public:
  enum { value = sizeof(has_xxx_impl<T>(0)) == sizeof(true_type) }; // comment3

};

struct Foo { int xxx() {return 0;}; };
struct Foo2 {};

int main() {
   static_assert(has_xxx<Foo>::value, "");
}
```

This is a struct to detect whether a struct has a certain method.
I have some questions about the code.

1. In comment 1, what does this '&C' mean, why can't I just write 'C::xxx'
2. In comment 2, what does the parameter '...' mean, is it a parameter pack, or it represents any kind of parameter
3. In comment 3, how does has_xxx_impl(0) work? T is replaced by Foo, then how about the parameter 0? why the first function is selected?

Comment: Writing this in C++14 is pretty nice :) [See it live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9229944f4e580ba7)

Comment: @melak47 : [muahaha](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a5e45495e5b273a)

Comment: [and here's how to address my previous example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ece49409d3bd1e2)

Comment: @AndyG : [muahaha](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fb1d9485dcaa2ce) :p

Comment: @melak47: You got me there :-) At that point we need some static casting, or to use expression SFINAE to select the appropriate overload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In comment 1, what does this '&C' mean, why can't I just write 'C::xxx'

The `&` is really referring to the `xxx` portion of `&C::xxx`. That is, get the address of the member `xxx` within `C` (which is hopefully a function, and not a static member --- more on that later)

> In comment 2, what does the parameter '...' mean, is it a parameter pack, or it represents any kind of parameter

the `...`, or ellipsis operator is a [variadic argument](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) that accepts anything. This is a pretty C-style way of doing things, and usually isn't very typesafe. The place you'll see it most today is in swallowing exceptions:

```
try{
ThrowableFunctionCall();
} catch(...) // swallow any exceptions
{}
```

(Note: this is NOT a parameter pack, or part of a fold expression. Refer to §5.2.2/6)

> In comment 3, how does has_xxx_impl(0) work? T is replaced by Foo, then how about the parameter 0? why the first function is selected?

`sizeof(has_xxx_impl<T>(0)) == sizeof(true_type)` is a sort-of clever way of using [overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) to set the value to `true_type` or `false_type`. Allow me to explain:

calling `has_xxx_impl<T>` at first makes it appear that both of

```
template <typename C>
static true_type has_xxx_impl(decltype(&C::xxx)); // comment 1

template <typename C>
static false_type has_xxx_impl(...); // comment 2
```

Are viable candidates, because they have the same name, and could maybe both be instantiated with type `T`. However

```
decltype(&C::xxx)
```

Is attempting to create a pointer to member type (e.g. `int(C::*)()` for member function pointer) and it's doing so in a type-deduced context. If the statement is ill-formed, then SFINAE takes effect and makes it a bad candidate, leaving us with only

```
template <typename C>
static false_type has_xxx_impl(...); // comment 2
```

and since `...` matches anything, the value is set to `false_type` or `long`.

If the statement is well-formed, then `0` can be properly assigned to a function pointer type (it is begrudgingly converted to a pointer type with a `null` value). This conversion is preferred over matching `...` ([try it yourself!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/139d9ec6813b0bac)), and hence the value takes on `true_type` which is a `char`.

Finally,

`value = sizeof(has_xxx_impl<T>(0)) == sizeof(true_type)`

we can say is either comparing size of `char` to size of `long` (doesn't have a `xxx` case)
or a size of `long` to a size of `long` (has a `xxx` case).

Note that all of this is completely unnecessary in C++11/14, and indeed fails if `xxx` is a member variable and not a function:

```
struct Foo3{static const int xxx;};
```

The comment by [melak47](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870124/how-does-sfinae-work-in-these-two-functions#comment57482825_34870124), while simpler, has a similar downfall.

A better solution would be to use the `is_member_function_pointer` type trait:

```
template<typename...> // parameter pack here
using void_t = void;

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct has_xxx : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct has_xxx<T, void_t<decltype(&T::xxx)>> :
  std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&T::xxx)>{};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ece49409d3bd1e2)

Answer (score 1):

Following explanation is imperfect and doesn't quote standard. I tried to explain it as understandable as possible.

`has_xxx_impl(decltype(&C::xxx))` accepts type which is produce by `decltype(&C::xxx)`
`&C::xxx` is a pointer to member and `decltype(&C::xxx)` is its type.

the other one `has_xxx_impl(...)` accepts "anything"

so, when you have `has_xxx_impl<T>` compiler must choose, one of above. It prefers the better match. So when type contains `xxx` the first one is better match than the `...` version.  If it doesn't contain such member, the function cannot be chosen and it has to use the other one (`...`)

Thanks to `SFINAE` - the substitution failure (when trying to pass type of non-existent member) doesn't produce an error (other overload is chosen)

Notice, that both functions returns different types (`true_type` and `false_type` which are defined to have distinct sizes) so with `sizeof(has_xxx_impl<T>(0)) == sizeof(true_type)` you can tell, which one was chosen. The result of this comparison is set as a `value` which you can access from the outside.

Comment: `is a member function pointer` it's "pointer to member" not exclusively to function. It can point to data members too

Comment: what is the difference between decltype(&C::xxx) and decltype(C::xxx). I tried decltype(C::xxx), it can only detect a member variable like struct { int xxx; }, it fails to detect a member function like struct { int xxx() {}; }. But decltype(&C::xxx) can detect both function and variable.

Comment: @SlardarZhang you can't pass a function by value. Also, the fact that it's a pointer is important. If you don't take the pointer then things like `std::string xxx` also wouldn't work. By taking the pointer the `0` that's passed to the function can be converted to it.